# How to raise the brightness on a computer using terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, display

How would I raise the brightness on my computer using terminal? Ideally, it would be done without executing an apple script or downloading external software, but whatever works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install **[Homebrew](http://brew.sh)**. (Bonus points for already having it installed)

Once that's all well and good, enter `brew install brightness`

Now, all you have to do is type in `brightness <level>` to change your laptop's brightness. Change `level` to your desired brightness on a scale of 0 to 1.

(example: enter `brightness .27` for 27% brightness)

---

Some bonus tips:

- entering `brightness -lv` will print some detailed info about your display, as well as your brightness level.
- `brightness -l` will give you *some* information about your display, but considerably less than `-lv`. It still prints your current brightness.
- The project is **[open-source on GitHub](https://github.com/nriley/brightness)**. Kudos to [@nriley](https://github.com/nriley) for making this project.

Comment: My MacBook is currently not working, so I can't look up the name of the setting, but it can be done with 'defaults write'. Homebrew is nice, but not necessary.

Comment: @WGroleau it's simply the easiest and cleanest way to do this.

Comment: Perhaps.  But "Ideally … without downloading" implies the OP would disagree.  I would think that identifying the correct keyword for something that comes with the O.S. would be no more difficult than installing homebrew then running it to install brightness.  I've used brew to install other things, and at least once it made me do something else first.

Comment: @WGroleau oops, missed that. home brew shouldn't require anything else for this script, it runs on my mac.